# Cloud Function & client authentication during HTTPS Call using firebase admin Auth

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, authorization

**Background:**
I have three entities (**language:** JS):

1. Client on Browser
2. Google Cloud Functions
3. An HTTP Server [Have Firebase admin Auth middleware]

So, From 1 and 2, I want to communicate with 3 using HTTPS calls.
Because the 3 has admin Auth already, I am able to authorize the calls from clients(1).

But I want to know how I can authorize calls from google cloud functions(2) so that I can securely communicate with both entities.

Token Auth Middleware:

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  console.log(await auth.getCredentials());
  if (
    (!req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) &&
    !(req.cookies && req.cookies.__session)
  ) {
    console.log(
      "No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header." +
        "Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:" +
        "Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>" +
        'or by passing a "__session" cookie.'
    );
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized 1");
    return;
  }

  let idToken;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")
  ) {
    console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
  } else if (req.cookies) {
    console.log('Found "__session" cookie');
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session;
  } else {
    // No cookie
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized 2");
    return;
  }

  try {
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    req.user = decodedIdToken;
    next();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while verifying Firebase ID token:" + error);
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized 3");
    return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to make an API call to your server from a Cloud function. If you are using `functions.https.onCall` callable function which automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens. So you don't get the actual ID Tokens unless you explicitly pass them.

To pass user info to your server, you can try either of these:

1. Explicitly pass the ID Token to the cloud function and then to your API which will verify the ID Token again.
2. As mentioned earler, the callable cloud function will automatically authenticate user and add the [`DecodedIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken) to `context.auth.token`. As the user is authenticated already you can simply pass the user's UID (and other claims if necessary) to your server for further processing. However, that means you'll have to configure your middleware in such a way that it accepts UID instead of tokens which can be misused by making random requests directly to server with some UIDs.

If you go with method 2, you would have to make sure that the requests are originated from your Cloud function only. This can be done by sharing a secret between cloud function and server and you can just attach that secret to every HTTP request you make to your server similar to an API key.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I am trying to make calls from clients and some calls from the functions too so I guess there might be 2 kinds of auth methods required.
Is there a method to authenticate one service account to another service account kinda.
Hope you got my point

Comment: @AkashSrivastava you should only have 1 service account if you are using same Firebase project I guess. When you are making direct call to server from client you can pass the ID token in authorization header as you are doing now. But when calling the API from the cloud function, you need to know which user called the callable function at first place so pass the ID token there. Can you be more clear about how the functions are triggered? If they are invoked by any client user then you can get the ID Token as explained my answer. Or is it a background function like Firestore trigger or so?

Comment: Hey @Dharmaraj, I got the point of passing the token ID. The calls are internal but we have user associated with each function call so I guess it can be implemented that way.